# Margin Left in Constraint Layout on Android does not work

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have tried to set the margins to a `ConstraintSet` into the `ConstraintSet.LEFT` anchor. But it doesn't work. However when using the `ConstraintSet.START` anchor, it works.

I am using constraints programmatically, and I tried setting the margins with both `ConstraintSet.connect`, as in:

(Does't work)

```
set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, MARGIN);
```

(Works)

```
set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, MARGIN);
```

And, I also tried with `ConstraintSet.setMargin`, as in:

(Doesn't work)

```
set.setMargin(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, MARGIN);
```

(Works)

```
set.setMargin(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, MARGIN);
```

Comment: Can you please post the lines which you tried?

Comment: Hi @Mandy8055, I just eddied the description adding the lines I am using.

Comment: I think its a bug see : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62154545

Comment: Yes, that is a defect. Use `START` and `END`.

Answer (score 0):

you must use START and END

```
set.setMargin(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, MARGIN);
```